# Picasa video wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, video, picasa

How can I play video from picasa.

I found that for every 11 hours the picasa will change the url.

Now I need to fetch the url of picasa video for every 11 hours by some cron job.
and dynamically need to append to player.

Anyone please help me out..

Thanks..

I have a url "https://picasaweb.google.com/110952422080907262131/February14201402?authkey=Gv1sRgCPzS0ITcnM33DA#5980149616210161090"

**HTML**

```
<object width="425" height="355">
<param name="movie" value="YOUR_VIDEO_URL"> </param> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"> </param> 
<embed src="picasaweb.google.com/110952422080907262131/…; type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355"> </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: <object width="425" height="355">
    <param name="movie" 
           value="YOUR_VIDEO_URL">
    </param>

    <param name="wmode" 
           value="transparent">
    </param>

    <embed src="https://picasaweb.google.com/110952422080907262131/February14201402?authkey=Gv1sRgCPzS0ITcnM33DA#5980149616210161090" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355">
    </embed>
</object>


I don't know how to get source url from picasa.
But It can be used to play video.. 
I read in some form..

This is the first time I am working with videos

Comment: Picasa has an api, but any integration is probably out of the scope of a single answer.  https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

Comment: It hasn't given information about how to embed or how to play videos in html5.

Please any one help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this kind of a link

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/110952422080907262131/February14201402#5980149616210161090
```

Not this

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/110952422080907262131/February14201402?authkey=Gv1sRgCPzS0ITcnM33DA#5980149616210161090
```

because the last link expire, the first NOT :)